# Soundcloud API only returning two results?

Tags: soundcloud

I am calling http://api.soundcloud.com/users/~~~~~.json?client_id=~~~~~ on the soundcloud API. It used to return 50 results, now it is only returning two with the exact same request. How do I get it back to 50?

Comment: I have the same problem and I suspect it comes from soundcloud..  the best option is to tell them

Comment: What do you have in the first ~~~~ after `users/`?  Their API has been having some issues, but I may be able to help with more context on what data you're looking to fetch.

Comment: Our call results have been inconsistent since 3/2/2016.  Some group's tracks are coming back ok, and other groups tracks aren't coming back at all even with a 200 OK.  As @platane mentions below, changing to an anonymous client id gets back all the results.

Comment: I am having this issue too. Things were working fine, now only returning 1 or 2 results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same thing here. I found out it is somehow related to the client_id.

I found it weird that my query returned nothing whereas there are plenty tracks returned when I use the soundcloud website.

You can grab the client_id given while browsing soundcloud as anonym. For me, the query with this client_id returned the expected result.

For example, the query
`api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=flume&client_id=02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea`
returns the expected track, whereas with my client_id I get none.

However I guess this can be a durable solution as the token probably expire.

I hope somebody from soundcloud can help us out here because there is no such things metioned in the documentation.

Comment: This is unfortunately the only way. I hope the soundcloud devs read this and get their act together.

Comment: So, our soundcloud rep says not to use that client_id although it works at the moment.  It's not guaranteed to work in the future. The vast majority of our calls started working again, but still some artists are blocked.  Apparently "Universal Music Group" made them block the API access for UMG artists.  Not sure when this will be resolved!

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that in general the API is returning sporadic results now, more than likely associated with the changes to the platform brought about by the introduction of the new subscription service soundcloud go.

I have seen territory restrictions and previews now added to tracks on the soundcloud site, and those tracks are excluded from results made via API calls. I am sure there are many other exclusions for as yet undocumented reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too. My client id is getting many 401's and blank screens where it used to work. But then if I plug in 02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea where my client id goes just like the first reply, it works fine. I sent an email to SoundCloud but they haven't replied. Anyone know if it's going to get fixed?